# Finding two areas of a rectangle separated by a line

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry

Given a rectangle and two points on the borders of the rectangle, where these two points will never share the same border, draw a line connecting these two points. Find the area of the two polygons formed by dividing the rectangle with this line. I am looking for an algorithm to find these two areas.

This seems like an easy problem but I couldn't find a consistent way to write the algorithm.

Here is an illustration of the problem with some example cases:

[image]

Comment: Formulas for area of triangle and trapezoid are well known. So what is real problem?

Comment: @MBo They are well known. The tricky part I realized was coming up with a formula that encompasses all possible point placements. A straightforward formula for a trapezoid that would work for the top left rectangle would not work for another rectangle where the two points are on the left and right borders. This eventually evolves into checking a lot of cases and various orientations which become tedious. Hence why I'm asking for an algorithm in hopes of an elegant solution.

Comment: So it is worth to describe this problem in question. Also you have to write how your rectangle and intersecting segments are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we examine the 6 possible configurations we see that in all cases the area of one polygon is equal to half the area of the rectangle formed by the endpoints of the line (red), plus an additional rectangle (green) in the case where the line spans the width or height of the outer rectangle.

[image]

The area of one polygon is therefore given by:

```
r1, r2 : corner points of the rectangle
p1, p2 : endpoints of the line

area = abs(p1.x - p2.x) * abs(p1.y - p2.y) / 2

if abs(p1.x - p2.x) == abs(r1.x - r2.x)
  area = area + abs(r1.x - r2.x) * (min(p1.y, p2.y) - min(r1.y, r2.y))
else if abs(p1.y - p2.y) == abs(r1.y - r2.y)
  area = area + abs(r1.y - r2.y) * (min(p1.x, p2.x) - min(r1.x, r2.x))
```

Comment: Nice, compact and efficient !

Comment: Nice illustrations, great answer as well! Thanks!

Comment: @RaffleBuffle can you clarify what exactly r1,r2 are? Is one corner of the rectangle always the origin and another always p1 (making r1,r2 the other two corners)?

Comment: @VainmondeDeCourtenay r1 and r2 are points in the plane - two points define a rectangle. In the context of your other question r1 = (0,0) and r2 = (m, n). Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Given two points of the straight line, you can pick the other two points from the corners of the rectangle to get the quadrilateral and then you could use the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula#Proof_for_a_quadrilateral_and_general_polygon) to compute the area of that quadrilateral.

If you find one quadrilateral area, you can find the other area just by subtracting first quadrilateral's area from the area of the whole rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 cases in total. Let say A and  B are the number of corners on the left and right side of the red line, respectively.
Case 1: A = B = 2, then there are 2 trapezoids.
Case 2: A = 1 or B = 1, then there is at least 1 triangle.